# How much am I 'trusted'?

Tags: feature-request

I gained a privilege to create tags which led me to a page where I saw a link: user trust (which I cannot access anymore). It caught my attention and I wondered why it isn't a tab in my profile, whether main or meta.

I noticed that the higher percentage your trust is, the more actions you are able to take as part of the community and in my opinion, your maturity, growth and perhaps performance. This info serves a similarly useful purpose as reputation but on a bit higher scale to me, if am right, and can encourage new users and those with low reps to make quality contribuions in answering and asking questions, commenting and meta activities.

I would really be happy if am able to see that near badges, votes and maybe privileges too, just to proudly see what has been achieved so far. They motivate me. Can it be done, or it's already done and am not seeing?

Answer (score 4):

I think the page you were referring to is the [Privileges](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges) page. For future reference, you can access the page by hovering over your name at the top of the site, and clicking "Privileges" on the dropdown.

And yes, you're right: the more reputation you have, the more you can do. Use the above link to see what you're allowed to do. The badge progress is harder to track, but you can see all the badges on the [badge page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/badges)

Comment: @ Thomas By 'future reference' do you mean it's yet to be put there? The privilege link you showed me is a general info about all the stages but I wish to see it display those that I have gained then probably from that I can know my trust level or probably see a display like USER TRUST 21%. As at now, I only remember only 2 out of the lot that I gained.

Comment: @Nok there is no "User Trust" level that I'm aware of. You can click each privilege on the right to see more detail, but that's about it.

Comment: @ Thomas oh, its rather Trusted User am talking about. But from the way it sounds I guess nothing is going to change. I may be suggesting quite strongly for this cos am about a week old and anxious. But thanks anyway.